# PostgreSQL join 2 rows into 1 row

Tags: postgresql, join

If there is a duplicate please point me to it. I don't know what keywords to use to search for this situation.
I have this table:

```
name    | read  | sum1  | sum2 
--------+-------+-------+-----
A       | 1     | 2.0   | 1.3
A       | 2     | 0.4   | 4  
B       | 1     | 0.2   | 0.1
B       | 2     | 1.0   | 3.3
```

What I want is this:

```
name    | r1_sum1 | r1_sum2  | r2_sum1 | r2_sum2 
--------+---------+----------+---------+--------
A       | 2.0     | 1.3      | 0.4     | 4
B       | 0.2     | 0.1      | 1.0     | 3.3
```

So it's like the rows are grouped by the `read`, and `name` columns. How do I do this in psql?

Comment: Does `read` take a fixed number of values, or could the desired query potentially return arbitrarily many columns?

Comment: @ruakh in most cases, `read` alternates from 1 to 2

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "in most cases" -- presumably you would like a query that covers *all* cases? -- but I've posted an answer based on my best guess of what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to itself:

```
SELECT t1.name AS name,
       t1.sum1 AS r1_sum1,
       t1.sum2 AS r1_sum2,
       t2.sum1 AS r2_sum1,
       t2.sum2 AS r2_sum2
  FROM insert_table_name_here AS t1
  FULL
 OUTER
  JOIN insert_table_name_here AS t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
   AND t1.read = 1
   AND t2.read = 2
;
```